# Vanilla NodeJS Cron Job?

Tags: node.js, docker, cron

I want to do something in node at, say, midnight each day.

I see a lot of stuff pointing me to `node-cron`, and I see [this](https://lukashermann.dev/writing/cron-in-nodejs-docker-image/) article configuring a docker container to execute a script per a crontab

I want to 1. not use any external packages and 2. keep the script being executed inside the server code itself (i.e. I couldn't have the docker container execute some other file on a schedule)

The use case is I want to update a cache on the server every day around midnight, and then, at more frequent intervals, use that cache for various things.

Comment: Add your script to `crontab`?

Comment: You can run multiple containers off of the same image.  One approach I routinely see here is to install the server code and also a cron daemon in the image, and override the container command to run a cron container with the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` to run the code every hour and check if it's around midnight

```
setInterval(() => {
  if (new Date().getHours() === 0) {
    // do stuff
  }
}, 1000 * 60 * 60)
```

Comment: Each hour would be `1000 * 60 * 60` no?